# Remove id once browser exceeds 640px

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive website with a grid system, once the screen goes under 640px then the grid size will change to 100% instead of 25% filling the screen width.

I then want to hide the remaining 3 divs and allow the user to scroll through them either with a button or touch.

I have this working so far but I can't get it to change back to the grid system once it exceeds 640px.

So my idea is to remove the id once the screen exceeds 640px

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalk/w6L87xv3/1/

Is this the best way to do it and how can I do this

Here's my query code but it doesn't work if you resize the browser only when you refresh it:

```
if($(window).width() > 640 )
{
    $('.swipe-container').removeAttr('id');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would also do the check whenever the window size changes. Put the code in a function, so that you can call it both when the page loads and when the window is resized.

You would also want to add the id again if the window shrinks below 640. Also, keep track of the state, so that you don't try to add or remove the id for every event.

```
var currentState = false;

function setSize() {
  var state = $(window).width() > 640;
  if (state != currentState) {
    currentState = state;
    if (state) {
      $('.swipe-container').removeAttr('id');
    } else {
      $('.swipe-container').attr('id', 'mySwipe');
    }
  }
}

setSize();
$(window).on('resize', setSize);
```

A simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/oxxxdww5/

Comment: Hi, it only deletes the id once the page is refreshed / loaded and not when it's been resized?

Comment: My bad, it does delete the id but the query overrides this until the page is refreshed. I'm going to have the do another slider

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger the resize on first load:

```
$(window).on('resize',function(){
//your code goes here
}).resize();//resize on load.
```

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not the best way to do this.

There are things called Media Queries in CSS

```
.swipe-container{
    witdh: 25%;
}

@media (max-width: 640px){
    .swipe-container{
        witdh: 100%;
    }
}
```

The idea here is that you have your standard properties, but make an exception for when the screen is bigger than 640px.
You can also do this the other way around with min-width:

```
.swipe-container{
    witdh: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 641px){
    .swipe-container{
        witdh: 25%;
    }
}
```

Please note that you should then exceed the given width (640px) by one.

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the replay, I learning about media queries now but i'm not sure how to get around this problem, if you take a look at my fiddle, the slider is working fine under 600px, when it exceeds this I want it to be a grid like the grid below in the sample and hide the pagination, any ideas how to do this?

Comment: You should then add a @media (min-width: 601px), with the properties that should change. For example you could set the pagination to display: none or visibility: hidden. And then let a grid appear (to do so, you would like to make one, but make it invisible. Then when the screen is wider than 600px, let it be visible)